# How to be sure that a layer is completely empty?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, stroke, layer-style

I've got a `.psd` file with multiple layers. Some layers "seem" empty. I say seem because I cannot see any element on them but I am not sure that there aren't some `1px` elements.

How can I be sure that some layers are 100% blank so that I can safely delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose `Layer > Layer Style > Stroke` and add a thick stroke (such as 6pts). Anything, even 1 pixel at 10% opacity, will become immediately visible.

Then if you need to retain the layer, simply remove the Layer Style.

Comment: Hey this may actually work :). I thought that selecting all would help somehow...

Comment: Selecting works if you have opaque pixels, but if you have a layer with less than 50% opacity, you won't see a selection either.

Answer (score 1):

I normally click on a layer and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (resize).

If I can see a resize box, it means there's something :)

Answer (score 0):

I would select the layer, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

I don't think this will delete pixels that are on the layer but off of the canvas, but it's super quick to do if you know it's all on the canvas.

Comment: I am sure I understand this

Answer (score 0):

Select magicwand tool while selecting the layer,[image] click on the canvas it will figure out the data if there.....

Comment: Unless the data is less than 50% opaque. Then you won't see any selection either.

Comment: in 0% Opacity & 0% fill Also we can find the selection in above screen shop i have been tried by keeping OPacity&Fill is nill....